# Relative number on old Vim versions

Tags: line-numbers

How can I get the relative number feature on old Vim versions (7.2 to be exact in my scenario) ?

I cannot install a newer version because other people are also using Vim on the same server.

Comment: Plugin specified in accepted answer still works for modern versions as well. (Very useful if you want normal numbers and relative numbers displayed side by side.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relative numbers were officially added to Vim with the 7.3 release.

If you can't update Vim or can't compile your own you will need to install a plugin like [DrChip's RltvNmbr](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2351). Maybe there are others. Note that it requires the `+signs` feature which you may or may not have.